# Task Owner in Email Template

Tags: tasks

I created a WFR to email a Task's Owner when a new task is created.  My problem is I can't pull in the Owner's name to the Email Template.

In Developer Console this SOQL query works:
SELECT Id, Owner.Name, Subject FROM Task WHERE Id = '00T63000003qXbf'

When I create the Email Template I tried to use {!Owner.Name} and {!Task.Owner.Name} but only get blanks in the email.  Any pointers what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 2):

You can use a VF email template:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Task Owner" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Task">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
Owner name: {!relatedTo.Owner.name}
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

When you test this in the **Send Test and Verify Merge Fields** option of the Template Editor, you'll get:

```
Owner name: Fred Fubar
```

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce didn't expose `Owner` related fields (in text based email templates, formula) in case of Task. Workaround could be create an Activity Custom field called `Owner Name` and update that field though trigger.

Use that custom field in the email template.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Custom Field on the Activity sObject and use that field in the Email Template.

The custom field is just a text formula and can be something like `Owner_Name__c` = `Owner:User.Full_Name__c`, where `Full_Name__c` is a custom name field on User sObject, then in your Email Template, you can use something like  `{!Task.Owner_Name__c}`